# How to connect nine dots with 4 straight lines without lifting the pen?

Tags: geometry, puzzle

I found this question [here](https://mindontest.blogspot.com/2019/08/nine-dots-puzzle-1.html) and I was able to find the one answer ,but with different perspective we have 2 more solutions.
Is it really possible or there is only 1 answer??

Comment: This question was asked here before, and probably deleted, because apart from the first solution which looks reasonable, the others are either incorrect or just not acceptable.

Comment: Mathematically the second solution is wrong, unless if you consider point with a small radius.

Comment: The intended solution is the first one with the four lines.  The question clearly uses the word "dot", not "disc".  Implicitly I think we can all understand it to mean "point", i.e. zero dimensional.  Thats how the original author of the riddle intended it.  In order to make the dots visible, naturally, they must appear like discs, because the real world is not ideal.

Comment: What they've done when they came up with those two additional solutions can be described by two nice English phrases: "Moving the goalposts" and "Thinking outside of the box". Usually you would use the latter if the "new" thing represents some important, useful, or otherwise intersting insight - the former is reserved for the cases where they just wanted to appear smart but have not done anything else of significance. I would say the two new solutions follow into the category of "moving the goalposts", on par with "allow for strategically placed black hoes to bend the straight lines..." ;)

Comment: Related: [How to prove the number of solutions to nine dots puzzle](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/565942/409)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably connect 9 dots in reflections across different directions. For example making it pointing down instead of up, or right, or left.
Hope that helps.